# Is there a way to pull code from AWS CodeCommit to an EC2 instance on a schedule through Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a file sagemaker.py in my codecommit, I want to pull it based on a schedule to an EC2. What is an easy way to accomplish this through terraform?

Comment: To an existing instance? Or to an instance which you create using terraform?

Comment: To an instance which I create using Terraform

Comment: Then you can use [User data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data) to provide code which will pull the file on the instance creation.

Comment: I want to pull when an instance is created and on a schedule after that

Comment: You can set it up all using user data. For scheduled pulling `cron` could be used. So you have to develop your own user data script which configures this behavior. Its not something that is provided by teraform. Teraform gives you ability to provide the `User data` which you develop yourself tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can also look at creating a systemd unit which you can then attach to your instance.